# React useState broken? state is not updated correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

see here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-hermann-5wsph

basically:

they keyboard used in the example, seems to get a wrong copy of the state

it fixes once you press shift on the keyboard. But other than that? the keyboard onKeyPress has the wrong `useState` variables.

what is the problem?

This:
[image]

the debug text is supposed to change IN THE CONSOLE, but doesn't. That means whatever I fire onKeyPress will have the wrong copy of the state variables except the ones I call in the callback.

That is just very very bad. I thought `useState` will solve those problems, not make them harder ?! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with React state but with the `Keyboard` component.

`react-simple-keyboard` does not realize that props have changed, so the `onKeyPress` function that you pass it always has the initial value.

When React state changes (the debug text), your `onKeyPressed` function in the `MyComponent` component will be recreated with the new values. In turn, the `onKeyPress` function inside your `KeyboardWrapper` also gets recreated.

This new function gets passed as a prop to `Keyboard`, but in the source code for `Keyboard` ([see here](https://github.com/hodgef/react-simple-keyboard/blob/master/src/lib/components/Keyboard.js)) a check is performed to see whether the props have changed.

The function that performs this check can be found [here](https://github.com/hodgef/react-simple-keyboard/blob/master/src/lib/services/Utilities.js):

```
export const propsChanged = (prevProps, props) => {
  const cleanProps = sourceObj =>
    JSON.stringify({
      ...sourceObj,
      stateToIgnore: null
    });

  return cleanProps(props) !== cleanProps(prevProps);
};
```

This function has a bug. When the props are 'cleaned', all functions are removed - which is a bit silly, since a function is a valid prop.

So the previous props (which includes your old `onKeyPress` function with the initial value of `debugText`) is 'cleaned' and compared with the new 'cleaned' props, and it looks to the `Keyboard` that the props have not changed, since neither the previous `clean` props or new `clean` props, have the `onKeyPress` function.

I added some logging to that function:

```
const previousProps = {
  onKeyPress: () => {
    console.log("Initial text");
  },
};

const newProps = {
  onKeyPress: () => {
    console.log("New text");
  },
};

const propsChanged = (prevProps, props) => {
  const cleanProps = (sourceObj) =>
    JSON.stringify({
      ...sourceObj,
      stateToIgnore: null,
    });

  console.log("original prev props:", prevProps);
  console.log("clean prev props:", cleanProps(prevProps));
  console.log("original new props:", props);
  console.log("clean new props:", cleanProps(props));

  return cleanProps(props) !== cleanProps(prevProps);
};

console.log(
  "does keyboard think props have changed?",
  propsChanged(previousProps, newProps)
);

console.log("have props actually changed?", previousProps !== newProps);

console.log("is there a bug with react-simple-keyboard?", true);
```

and here is the result:

```
original prev props: { onKeyPress: [Function: onKeyPress] }
clean prev props: {"stateToIgnore":null}
original new props: { onKeyPress: [Function: onKeyPress] }
clean new props: {"stateToIgnore":null}
does keyboard think props have changed? false
have props actually changed? true
is there a bug with react-simple-keyboard? true
```

I suggest filing an issue over on [their github repo](https://github.com/hodgef/react-simple-keyboard).

Comment: I just got a message from the author saying `react-simple-keyboard` has been updated with a fix. Install v2.3.0 and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Toskan If my answer helped then please mark it as accepted so that the question can be closed.